# What is simplest reactive programming language?

Tags: reactive-programming

I teach a course in Programming Paradigms. Last year I used Elm as an example of (Functional) Reactive Programming. This summer I noticed that Elm is no longer FRP (according to http://elm-lang.org/blog/farewell-to-frp). I'm looking for another vehicle, one for which I don't have to first teach a lot of syntax.

Reactive Programming in JavaScript seems way too complex. My students will have learned some Scala, but I haven't found a good tutorial on RP in Scala.

Suggestions, anyone? Requirements: reactive, simple syntax.

Comment: Hi! I maintain Yampa (https://github.com/ivanperez-keera/Yampa). It uses a model similar to circuit design, which can be very simple. I'd like to know what you think, and even if you would not use it for this course, I'd like to know what itches you so we can make Yampa better.

Comment: I'll try to look into it.

Comment: If you teach CS, you might be interested in https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/ (though since it's still in private beta, it's easiest to enter through here https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators)

Answer (score 1):

You can also check Reactor for Spring ecosystem https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

I suggest RxJava with Java8. It is well documented and maintained. There is a lot of materials- books, articles, tutorials, conference talks, etc.

'reactive, simple syntax'.. 
I do not see much in common between syntax and being reactive. Java8 has excellent free IDE support (Intellij or Eclipse). For me, it is important in learning new language than paradigim- more important than language itself.